# Plot average of scattered values in 2D bins as a histogram/hexplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 dimensional scattered data x, y, z. 
I want to plot the average of z in bins of x and y as a hex plot or 2D histogram plot.
Is there any matplotlib function to do this? 
I can only come up with some very cumbersome implementations even though this seems to be a common problem.

E.g. something like this:

[image]

Except that the color should depend on the average z values for the (x, y) bin (rather than the number of entries in the (x, y) bin as in the default hexplot/2D histogram functionalities).

Comment: Have a look at the matplotlib `tricontour` function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'd like to get around performing a triangulation in the (x,y) space (I feel this would be hard to interpret in the parts where I have very little to None data). While already being implemented, this seems to be a harder problem than what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If binning is what you are asking, then `binned_statistic_2d` might work for you. Here's an example:

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(10, 20, 1000)
z = np.exp(-(x-3)**2/5 - (y-18)**2/5) + np.random.random(1000)

x_bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y_bins = np.linspace(10, 20, 10)

ret = binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, statistic=np.mean, bins=[x_bins, y_bins])

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax0.scatter(x, y, c=z)
ax1.imshow(ret.statistic.T, origin='bottom', extent=(0, 10, 10, 20))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

@Andrea's answer is very clear and helpful, but I wanted to mention a **faster alternative that does not use the scipy library**.

The idea is to do a 2d histogram of x and y weighted by the z variable (it has the sum of the z variable in each bin) and then normalize against the histogram without weights (it has the number of counts in each bin). In this way, you will calculate the average of the z variable in each bin.

The code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 10**7)
y = np.random.uniform(10, 20, 10**7)
z = np.exp(-(x-3)**2/5 - (y-18)**2/5) + np.random.random(10**7)

x_bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y_bins = np.linspace(10, 20, 50)

H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [x_bins, y_bins], weights = z)
H_counts, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [x_bins, y_bins]) 
H = H/H_counts

plt.imshow(H.T, origin='lower',  cmap='RdBu',
            extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

In my computer, this method is approximately a **factor 5 faster** than using scipy's `binned_statistic_2d`.