# 2D histogram with a three variables

Tags: python, plot, 2d, histogram

I need some ideas here. I have a data frame with several columns: A, B, C, D...., Z for example. I need to plot a 2D histogram (in Python) of A and B against another variable (say C) from the df. How can I do it? So basically, I want to have another parameter C in place of the normal colorbar in the 2D hist plot.

Comment: You mean you want a bar plot ? (histogram is not that).

Comment: No I meant a 2D histogram. But with a third variable plotted in the counts axis (colorbar).

Comment: I think this is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58937863/12131616